# Multiple loops code migration to java 8: is it the best way?

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following old style java multiple loop which I want to convert to Java 8 streams:

```
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(3,5,6);
    List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(3,4,9);
    boolean match = true;

    int list1Size = list1.size();
    int list2Size = list2.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < list1Size; i++ ) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list2Size && i < list1Size; j++) {
            if (list2.get(j).equals(list1.get(i))) {
                if (list3.get(j).equals(list1.get(i))) {
                    System.out.println(list1.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

(The output is: 3)

The best way I could find was:

```
    IntStream.range(0, list1Size).forEach(
            ix1 -> {
                    IntStream.range(0, list2.size()).forEach(
                            ix2 -> {
                                if (ix2 < list2.size() && ix1 < list1.size())
                                    if (list2.get(ix2).equals(list1.get(ix1))) {
                                        if (list3.get(ix2).equals(list1.get(ix1))) {
                                            System.out.println(list1.get(ix1));
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                    );
            }
    );
```

which doesn't seem too attractive to me...

Please note that I am working with 3 lists using 2 loops.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why are you using a variable match that does not change inside the loop?

Comment: Dont need to convert all readable loops to streams. If you want to use stream, do it when it will help improve readability

Comment: @DanielMesejo Sorry, it is a redundant leftover...

Comment: Just to check, you are verifying the elements that are common to the 3 lists?

Comment: If loop is more readable then you should keep using it. In your particular case readability is degraded. There is NO requirement to migrate EVERY loop to functional style

Comment: `i < list1Size` in your second loop is redundant

Comment: (I believe) several answers have misunderstood your original code. Why don't you explain your objective to encourage the most appropriate answer, not just a literal translation?

Comment: I read it as meaning: "find the set of common elements (across all 3 lists), where said element is in the same position in lists 2 & 3"

Comment: Guys, to make things clear - I am searching for common numbers in lists.

Comment: But also, it interests me if for should be ultimately converted to streams or not if you want to advance to j8?

Comment: So... you don't care whether they are at the same index?

Answer (score 0):

Since the index of the element in the first `List` doesn't really matter, you can `Stream` over the elements of `list1` and search for an element of `list1` that appears on both `list2` and `list3` at the same index:

```
Optional<Integer> result = 
    list1.stream()
         .filter(IntStream.range(0,list2.size())
                          .filter(i -> list2.get(i).equals(list3.get(i)))
                          .mapToObj(list2::get)
                          .collect(Collectors.toSet())::contains)
        .findFirst();
```

Or if you just want to print the first match:

```
list1.stream()
     .filter(IntStream.range(0,list2.size())
                      .filter(i -> list2.get(i).equals(list3.get(i)))
                      .mapToObj(list2::get)
                      .collect(Collectors.toSet())::contains)
     .limit(1)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The `IntStream` pipeline generates a `Set` of all the elements that appear in both `list2` and `list3` in the same index. The `filter` searches for elements of `list1` that belong to that `Set`.

Comment: @DanielMesejo Once. The `filter()` method is executed once, and a method reference to an instance method of a specific Set instance is passed to it.

Comment: I think, `findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println)` is more idiomatic than `.limit(1).forEach(System.out::println)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>(list1);

IntStream.range(0, Math.min(list2.size(), list3.size()))
        .filter(i -> Objects.equals(list2.get(i), list3.get(i))) // check where index have the same value
        .mapToObj(list2::get) // get the value (as the values are equal could be also list3)
        .filter(set1::contains) // check if list1 contains the value
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output**

```
3
```

Transforming `list1` into a set (`set1`) gives you a healthy speed-up by improving the performance of the containment query (`O(n) -> O(1)`).

Answer (score 0):

If position isn't important, and you use `Set` instead, this becomes quite trivial:

```
set1.retainAll(set2);
set1.retainAll(set3);
```

With streams you could do:

```
set1.stream()
   .filter(set2::contains)
   .filter(set3::contains)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```